# Basic Percentage Calculation

Tags: percentages

I'm working on a project and need the following help, although that this may be basic to some people, I am struggling to work out this calculation.

Let's say there are currently 3 tasks, and the a student has to complete all of these 3 tasks to get 100%. Let's say that I student has completed 1 of these tasks, the percentage that has been completed is: $ (1 / 3) \cdot 100 $ which will gives $33.33$%..

But, how will can I calculate the percentage still remaining (out of 100)?

Comment: Have you tried 100-33.33?

Comment: @orion Thank you. I knew the answer was simple!